# Combining Sliding Windows Over Many Time-Series in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have many (O(1 million)) time series each with about 30 time-steps. The number of time steps varies between samples. I would like to use a sliding window over each time series to generate training samples. The target is the time step immediately proceeding each window. Storing the result of each sliding window into a new array would be memory wasteful, so I would like to use Tensorflow.Dataset pipeline.

for example data we can generate 100 samples each with 15 time steps and 3 features each.
`data = np.ones(100,15,3)`

```
def window_data(data):
    window_size = 3
    n_features = 3
    tmp_in = None
    tmp_out = None
    
    for i in range(data.shape[0]-window_size):
        a = data[np.newaxis,i:i+3]
        if tmp_in is None:
            tmp_in = a
            tmp_out = data[i+window_size]
        else:
            tmp_in = np.append(tmp_in,a,axis=0)
            tmp_out = np.append(tmp_out, data[i+window_size])
            
    return tmp_in, tmp_out.reshape(tmp_out.shape[0]//n_features, n_features)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda i: tf.py_function(func=window_data, 
                                               inp=[i], 
                                               Tout=[tf.float32,
                                                     tf.float32]
                                               ), 
                      num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

However this results in a dataset where each element is has shape `(sample_size - window_size, window_size, n_features)` whereas I need a dataset where each element is a window of size `(window_size, n_features)`

Is it possible to perform a sliding window over many time series datasets and combine the results efficiently into a tensorflow dataset?